# Scaling images w/jQuery - browser cache in the way

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, caching

To see my problem in action, 1st click [this link](http://www.apoads.com/Yokota/Ad/Photo). Then click [this one](http://www.apoads.com/CampZama/Ad/Photo). Notice how the images are squished? (you may have to click a through the pager to see it).

I believe it's because of the browser cache. Here's the javascript doing the work:

```
$("#grid_slider").slider({
    value: 50,
    max: 100,
    min: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('ul#grid li').css('font-size',ui.value+"px");
    }
});

$("ul#grid li img").each(function() {
    var width = $(this).width() / 125 + "em";
    var height = $(this).height() / 125 + "em";
    $(this).css("width",width);
    $(this).css("height",height);
});
```

I hope you're able to reproduce the problem. Not sure what needs to be done to fix this... was thinking about just taking out the feature all-together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen your page and still don't understand the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "squished"? When I load the page, there is a flicker where I see the images large and then they shrink. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yea, I was afraid you wouldn't be able to reproduce the problem. It looks like it works on the first load... then when the order of the images changes some of the images become "squished". 

It's a little difficult to explain I suppose... hopefully the issue crops up when someone other than myself visits the page.

Comment: Oops, try again... Example of problem (wrong, squished images): http://img99.imageshack.us/i/snapshot6.png/ After hitting reload (correct, expected result): http://img134.imageshack.us/i/snapshot7.png/

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem you're describing. I don't think it's the browser cache, actually, but the load time... I've seen the problem on some other sites too, and so I've formed an (ill-informed) opinion on it.

It appears that the main issue is that the browser is being asked the image's size before it knows what that is... Your script fires on `$(document).ready`, but that might be before `$("ul#grid li img")` is fully loaded, so for some images `$("ul#grid li img").width()` might not be known...

Maybe use this instead, and see if that helps? (switches `$().each` for `$().load`)

```
$("ul#grid li img").load(function() {
    var width = $(this).width() / 125 + "em";
    var height = $(this).height() / 125 + "em";
    $(this).css("width",width);
    $(this).css("height",height);
})
```

(Completely a guess, though...)

Addendum: reading the jQuery help on the load function just now, it appears that this doesn't get run for things already loaded by the time this is called... So you might have to do both (call `$().each` and set `$().load`)...

Comment: Hmm... that makes sense. Will look into delaying the resize... or hard coding the image size at load.